# How to replace a value in a Pandas Dataframe Index with another given a date range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a multi-index Pandas Dataframe that has a structure like this

```
df1
                 value
Key1 date
A    2010-01-01      1
     2010-01-02      2
         ...
B    2010-01-01      1
     2010-01-02      1
```

I have another Dataframe that looks like this that maps Key1 to Key2 for a specified date range:

```
df2
          start_date end_date
Key1 Key2 
A    AA   2010-01-01 2011-01-01
A    AAA  2011-01-01 2012-01-01
B    BB   2010-01-01 2011-01-01
        ...
```

How would I replace Key1 with Key2 in `df1` given the range of dates for Key2? I have tried to make a new table and expand all the dates so I can directly replace each index but am having trouble with the multi-index. Any help appreciated.

Comment: This might work: df1['Key1'].replace(to_replace=df2['Key1'].tolist(),value=df2['Key2'].tolist(),inplace=True)

Answer (score 0):

You can merge both tables on their key1 and drop the columns that you don't want to have

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Key1')
df.drop('date', axis = 1)
```

you can drop as much as you want and if they are not identical in means of dates. You can delete nulls with dropna() function.